The biggest spiral submatrix program written in C doesn't return what's expected
My program should return the biggest spiral submatrix. For 2x2 matrix with values [[1,2], [4,3]] it returns 2x2 submatrix with same values (as it should), but when I enter 2x3 matrix with values [[1,2,5], [4,3,9]] it doesn't return anything, just prints that there are no spiral submatrices.
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<string.h>

void printMat(int n, int m, int mat[n][m]);
int isSpiral(int n, int m, int mat[n][m]);
void printSpiral(int n, int m, int mat[n][m]);
void copyMat(int n, int m, int mat[n][m], int mat2[n][m]);

int main(void) {
    int n, m;
    printf("Enter number of rows and columns: \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    int mat[n][m];
    printf("Enter %d elements of matrix: \n", n * m);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printMat(n, m, mat);
    printSpiral(n, m, mat);
    return 0;
}

void printMat(int n, int m, int mat[n][m]) {
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("%5d", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int isSpiral(int n, int m, int mat[n][m]) {
    int k = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i <= n / 2 && k < n * m; i++) {

             if((i > 0) && (mat[i][i] - mat[i][i - 1] != 1))
                return 0;
            else
                k++;

            for(int j = i; j < m - 1 - i && k < n * m; j++) {
                k++;
                if(mat[i][j + 1] - mat[i][j] != 1)
                    return 0;
            }

            for(int j = i; j < n - 1 - i && k < n * m; j++) {
                k++;
                if(mat[j + 1][m - 1 - i] - mat[j][m - 1 - i] != 1)
                    return 0;
            }

            for(int j = i; j < m - 1 - i && k < n * m; j++) {
                k++;
                if(mat[n - 1 - i][j] - mat[n - 1 - i][j + 1] != 1)
                    return 0;
            }

            for(int j = i + 1; j < n - 1 - i && k < n * m; j++) {
                k++;
                if(mat[j][i] - mat[j + 1][i] != 1)
                    return 0;
            }
        }
    return 1;
}

void copyMat(int n, int m, int mat[n][m], int mat2[n][m]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            mat2[i][j] = mat[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void printSpiral(int n, int m, int mat[n][m]) {
    int mat3[n][m], i2 = 0, j2 = 0;
    int maxi2 = -1, maxj2 = -1;
    int mat2[n][m];

    for(int g = n; g > 1; g--) {

        for(int f = m; f > 1; f--) {

            for(int k = 0; k < g - 1; k++) {

                for(int l = 0; l < f - 1; l++) {

                    i2 = 0;
                    for(int i = k; i < g; i++) {
                        j2 = 0;
                        for(int j = l; j < f; j++) {
                            mat2[i2][j2] = mat[i][j];
                            j2++;
                        }
                        i2++;
                    }

                if(isSpiral(i2, j2, mat2)) {
                    if(i2 >= maxi2 && j2 >= maxj2) {
                        maxi2 = i2;
                        maxj2 = j2;
                        copyMat(maxi2, maxj2, mat2, mat3);
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(maxi2 > 0 && maxj2 > 0)
        printMat(maxi2, maxj2, mat3);
    else
        printf("\nNo spiral submatrix");
}


I tried debugging it but it didn't help much. I noticed that when it calls isSpiral function from printSpiral function it returns 0 for [[1,2], [4,3]] submatrix and it returns it when variable k is equal to 3 at second nested for, which shouldn't do.
This my first time asking question here so I apologize in advance if my question doesn't have proper form.

When you single-step through the program in a debugger, what is the first point at which it does something you do not want it to do?

I put breakpoint at printSpiral and everything went well until for submatrix (one stored in mat2 = {{1,2}, {4,3}}) it called isSpiral and in isSpiral in like second for loop it somehow reached return 0 which shouldn't be possible for that case. Hope this clear things up.

The problem was the way I was declaring my functions parameters.
Here, I created isSpiral(int n, int m, int mat[n][m]), and the problem was int mat[n][m], because n and m would change the size of my mat variable (matrix).
If the size was changed, the function would get wrong indexes, so I just added two new parameters, int i2 and int j2:
isSpiral(int n, int m, int i2, int j2, int mat[i2][j2]).
That way, the size of my matrix remains the same, constant, as it should, and limits for submatrices are variable.

It only changed what your program thought was the size of the array. Passing an array as a function argument will always pass it as a pointer to the array. The size you provide (the n and m in mat[n][m]) in a function argument are only there for you. The compiler may cause warnings, if you disregard the maximum size, if it detects that at compile time, but it will never actually have an effect at what your program does.

I understand, but I implemented it without using pointers (even though the matrix name itself is a pointer)  and without dynamically allocating memory. So if I didn't add those two parameters in functions: void printMat(int n, int m, int i2, int j2, int mat[i2][j2]), int isSpiral(int n, int m, int i2, int j2, int mat[i2][j2]) and
void copyMat(int n, int m, int i2, int j2, int mat[i2][j2], int mat2[i2][j2])  and if I didn't provide the size of mat that would create a logical error which I tried to explain earlier, but I wasn't successful with it. @Tenobaal
